# Suppose you put free charge on a conductor. After how long will it reach the surface?

Tags: electromagnetism

Iam unable to solve this question.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoiAx.jpg)

Comment: This image should be discarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a localized mobile (electron) charge into a conductor, it will, under the influence of its own electric field decay and disperse and move to the outer limits of the conductor where it forms a surface charge.

The characteristic time for this exponential decay can (very roughly) be estimated from the **dielectric relaxation time** (or "Maxwell's time") $$ \tau=\frac {\epsilon}{\sigma}$$ where $\epsilon=\epsilon_0\epsilon_r$ is the absolute permittivity, and $\sigma=ne\mu$ is the specific conductivity of the conductor with $n$ the electron concentration, $e$ the electron charge, and $\mu$ the electron mobility in the conductor. In typical metals with a specific conductivity on the order of $\sigma=1·10^5\Omega^{-1}cm^{-1}$ and permittivity $\epsilon=1·10^{-12}Fcm^{-1}$ the dielectric relaxation time is on the order of $$\tau∼10^{-17}s$$ which is extremely short.